# Recommend way of scoping private members in javascript module

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Conside the following JavaScript code.  The function definitions all seem to achieve the same thing.  Is there any recommended convention for defining the functions which are then 'revealed' in the return dictionary object?

```
var testModule = (function(){
      var counter = 0;

      var localFunc1 = function() {
        return "local 1";
      }

      function localFunc2() {
        return "local 2";
      }

      this.localFunc3 = function() {
        return "local 3";
      }

      localFunc4 = function() {
        return "local 4";
      }

      return {      
        proxy1: localFunc1,
        proxy2: localFunc2,
        proxy3: localFunc3,
        proxy4: localFunc4
      };
    })();
```

Comment: The recommended way is to not do it, at all. Privates are just not worth the hassle

Comment: Privates are essential for building library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is any real preferred method.  The most common setup I've seen involves creating all of your methods as local (using var) then returning an object that exposes the public methods.

A couple of things to note:

- this.localFunc3 will only work if your object is instantiated with the 'new' keyword
- when returning your object, remove the () from each function so that you are returning a reference to the function and not the function's returned value
- localFunc4 will be global since it has no 'var' keyword in front of it

When working with a module pattern like this, I tend to go for something along the lines of:

```
var Obj = ( function () {
    var private_static = 'this value is static';
    return function () {
        //-- create return object
        var _self = {};
        //-- create private variables
        var private_variable = 'this value is private';
        var func1 = function () {
            return 'value 1';
        };
        //-- attach public methods
        _self.func1 = func1;
        //-- return the object
        return _self;
    };
} )();
```

Some notes about this method:

- allows for private static variables (if you don't need private static variables, you can remove the closure)
- by creating the _self reference first, you can pass a self reference to any objects instantiated from within that need a reference to their parent
- I like that I can reference all internal functions without _self.whatever or this.whatever, ignoring whether or not they are private or public

Comment: I checked this, localFunc3 works without using new. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Robert, withot `new`, `this` will refer to the window. That's why his `localFunc3` works.

Comment: Ah, yea, my mistake.  Removed my flawed explanation.  =)

Answer (score 1):

The definitions do not achieve the exact same thing.

- `var localFunc1` and `function localFunc2` do the same thing, they create functions only available inside your outer function.
- `this.localFunc3` and `localFunc4` are not really local functions: they both belong to the `window` object (`this` in that context is `window`, and `localFunc4` is declared without the `var` statement).

So, the latter two don't even need to be exposed on your returned object, since they're already global. And, actually, you are not exposing any functions on your return object, you are exposing their return values, since you invoke each of them. Were you trying to do this?

```
return {      
   proxy1: localFunc1,
   proxy2: localFunc2,
   proxy3: localFunc3,
   proxy4: localFunc4
};
```

**Note**: I recommend you watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg&feature=plcp&context=C46cf573VDvjVQa1PpcFPAdPdv90ATO5RJ8BG3i_k0nAUW1D_pQBQ=) where Douglas Crockford explains the multiple ways to deal with inheritance in JavaScript. I believe you are looking for what he calls "parasitic inheritance".

Comment: No, you're correct.  The returned proxies should be pointing to the functions not their return value. Thanks for picking this up. I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: I've debugged the code and it seems localFunc3 and localFunc4 are NOT on the window object. Can you confirm this?  Isn't this because the testModule is scoping 'this' due to being a self-invoking function?

Comment: @jaffa, `this` should be `window`, unless your object is instanced with `new`. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NuV9R/).